# Multiplication on ordinal number

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Can I prove "Let $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ be ornidal numbers. If $\alpha \cdot \beta = \alpha \cdot \gamma$ and $\alpha > 0$, then $\beta=\gamma$."?

Comment: Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic) says that you can. ("Multiplication is strictly increasing and continuous in the right argument: ($\alpha \lt \beta$ and $\gamma \gt 0$) $\Rightarrow  \gamma \cdot\ \alpha \lt \gamma \cdot\ \beta$")

Comment: @user8734617 Ok, I will try to use contrapositive method in this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $0 < \alpha$ and $\beta < \gamma$. Then
$$
\alpha \cdot \beta < (\alpha \cdot \beta) + \alpha = \alpha \cdot(\beta +1) \le \alpha \cdot \gamma.
$$